# execute() method in tasklet is not invoking

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Below is the code :

```
@Configuration
public class Job {

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.batch.core.Job createJob() {

        System.out.println("JOBSTEP");

        return new JobBuilder("createJob", jobRepository).start(firstStep()).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Step firstStep() {

        System.out.println("STEPMETHOD");
        // return new StepBuilder("firstStep", jobRepository).tasklet(new
        // FirstStepTasklet(), transactionManager).build();

        return new StepBuilder("firstStep", jobRepository).tasklet(firstStepTasklet(), transactionManager).build();
    }

    

    @Bean
    public Tasklet firstStepTasklet() {
        System.out.println("taskletmethod");
        return new Tasklet() {

            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("This is first step");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

`Job`, `Step`, and `Tasklet` gets called but the overridden `execute` method inside Tasklet is not called. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You are only defining beans here. How are you launching the job?

Comment: You seem to be using Spring Boot 3. Do you have `@EnableBatchProcessing` somewhere? This could be the issue, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes

Comment: HI,
@EnableBatchProcessing is added to the main application class and job is launched from main class

Answer (score -1):

Remove @EnableBatchProcessing from the Main class or from Configuration class.